# where to locate the relay switch on the blower of a vauxhall vectra

Tags: heater-blower

Blower not working at all in vectra.  c 03 plate.
Did have water coming in and have removed and replaced the cabin filter. I have located the resistor but do not know about the relay.

Answer (score 1):

In your fascia fuse box: Fuse No. 2 is for the AC/heater blower relay. Same fuse box you have two rows of relays, with three relays each row. There is also a smaller relay on its own, call that the bottom row. The blower relay is on the top row of relays, number three, and is directly in line with the smaller relay at the bottom.(Sorry- no picture). Fuse is a 7.5amp/brown one.